# animated element changes width in size every few pixels on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, css

A video scrub handle that I have on my page appears to warp in width whenever it is animating to the right or left (to show the progress of the video / when the user is scrubbing).

How the circle **should** look at all times (even when moving):

[image: before moving a couple of pixels]

How it looks when moving (after every couple of pixels):

[image: after moving a couple of pixels]

This is the **HTML** for the scrub handle, and it's container (progress bar):

```
<!-- 
    the 9.67197% is generated via JavaScript;
    as the width of the container (progress bar) increases, the scrub handle stays true 
    to the right of the container;
!-->
<div class="player-scrubber_elapsed" id="player_si02" style="width: 9.67197%;">
    <div role="handle" id="player_cs02"></div>
</div>
```

and the **CSS** for the scrub, and progress bar:

```
/* progress bar */
.player-scrubber_elapsed{
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    background: rgba(225, 6, 47, 0.87);
}
/* scrub handle */
.player-scrubber_elapsed #player_cs02{
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -6px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #e1062f;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.71);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 120ms ease-out;
}
```

**JsFiddle** for live example: https://jsfiddle.net/zc5yubbn/

If anyone could tell me how to prevent this issue, it would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

**NOTE**: I have noticed that on a regular sized monitor, it appears to work fine. **However**, on a smaller laptop screen, where the Windows user interface is scaled to `125%`, it will start to warp.

Comment: in chrome it stays the same size but moves..

Comment: @wawmsey I'm in chrome, and it appears to change size for me - interesting.

Comment: indeed! which version? i'm 60.0.3112.113

Comment: @wawmsey currently  60.0.3112.113 as well. However, if you check the new edit, you'll notice that it might have something to do with the DPI scaling on smaller computer screens :/